# Can a derived class access a private method of a protected inner class of the parent class that is a friend of the inner class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, inner-classes, friend

Considering this class:

```
class Matchable
{
  protected:
    class Match {
      friend class Matchable;

      void append( const Match& match ) {}
    };

  public:
    virtual bool match( const Source& source ) = 0;
};
```

... where the outer class `Matchable` is a friend of the inner class `Match`, and considering this class:

```
class Literal : public Matchable {

  bool match( const Source& source ) override {
    Matchable::Match m;
    Matchable::Match cm;

    m.append( cm );

    return true;
  }

}
```

... where `Literal` is derived from `Matchable`, I seem to be able to instantiate `Matchable::Match` in `Literal::match()` without a problem, yet I am unable to call the private method `Matchable::Match::append()`, where I expected `Literal` to inherit the "friendliness" of `Matchable`.

Is this expected behavior and if so, is there a way to make `Literal` access private methods of its parent inner class `Match`?

Comment: "Can a derived class access a private method of a protected inner class of the parent class that is a friend of the inner class?" ... Only if it uses Brawndo .. It's got electrolytes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. See [friend declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)

> Friendship is not inherited (your friend's children are not your friends)

You might provide a delegate method in `Matchable`:

```
class Matchable
{
  protected:
    class Match {
      friend class Matchable;
      void append( const Match& match ) {}
    };
    void appendMatch( Match& match, const Match& matched ) { 
        match.append(matched);
    }

  public:
    virtual bool match( const Source& source ) = 0;
};
```

then

```
class Literal : public Matchable {

  bool match( const Source& source ) override {
    Matchable::Match m;
    Matchable::Match cm;

    appendMatch(m, cm);

    return true;
  }

}
```

Otherwise you might make `Match::append` `public` (which make friend declaration meaningless).

Comment: Right on, thank you! Seeing that this is the case, is your suggestion a commonly used solution, or am I just abusing friend classes this way? Would you, for instance, suggest a completely different approach, for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @DecentDabbler I'll suggest making `Match::append` a `public` method. Making it `private` and using `friend` lead to complex code. Do you have any special reason for making it `private`?

Comment: I'd rather not make it `public` because ultimately I want to return the `Match` instance from the `match()` method (there is going to be a second argument to `match()` in the future) and let it be "immutable" to consumers of `match()` (if that makes sense).

Comment: @DecentDabbler It's not clear. If you want to make `Match` the 2nd parameter of `match()`, it means the caller of `match` could instantiate `Match`. But only the derived class of `Matchable` could do that. Is it right?

Comment: Ouch, you are right, of course! Good point! I'm new to c++ and I may not have thought this through enough. Would it be possible to have the second parameter initially be an untyped null pointer, perhaps? Or does a parameter always have to be typed? I'm porting this from PHP, where the second argument is a reference that is initially `null` (references in PHP can be `null`). What I'm trying to achieve is to fill the second parameter with a `Match` instance only if `match()` returns `true`, otherwise I want to keep it `null`. Or is this unheard of in c++ land?

Comment: An untyped pointer, or a Match pointer that is null? Passing a null pointer for the function to "fill" is a common C idiom. A null pointer in C++, since C++1,1 can be declared with the keyword
    nullptr -
I don't know if that's the best way to do what you want (I'm just skimming) but it's a recognizable approach. You don't want an untyped pointer (void *), I assume.

Comment: @DecentDabbler It's possible, if you pass the pointer by reference, (i.e. `Matchable::Match*&`), initially `nullptr`, then initialize it or not in the function. But you'll have the same problem too, only the derived class of `Matchable` could use `Matchable::Match`, otherwise you can't write `Matchable::Match* match_ptr = nullptr;`.

Comment: Wait, I think I've got the solution: I could make `Matchable::Match` a `public` class, yet still have `Matchable::Match::append()` stay `private` (and thus accessible to the friend), correct? What I'm trying to achieve is that `match()` can build a complex `Matchable::Match` object graph, but be immutable for the consumer of `match()` (and I want to avoid the Builder design pattern). I'm just gonna go ahead and give it a try. Thank you for your valuable input so far!

Comment: @DecentDabbler It seems fine. Note that the delegate method is still needed. Anyway, good luck. :)

Comment: @mock_blatt Thanks for thinking along with us. I'm not sure I understand the intricacies of pointers / `void*` / etc. enough yet, so I'll do some more research to understand exactly what you are asking me. In the meantime I think I've probably come up with a workable solution as well. Although I now see that the inner class *indeed* is unnecessary now, if I just declare `Matchable` as friend of this `Match`. Uch... haha. ;-)